# How to process incoming pdf in ASP.NET Core Web API using C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building an ASP.NET Core Web API in C#. I receive a PDF file in the request body.

When I write the bytes of the request body, I get a file having base64 string (which should be decoded to get the actual PDF).

I don't know what to do next .. please advise ..

```
var ms = new MemoryStream((int)Request.ContentLength);
req.CopyToAsync(ms).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("test.pdf", ms.ToArray());
```

When I open `test.pdf`, I get something like the below:

```
JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBl............cnR4cmVmDQoxODkzOQ0KJSVFT0Y=
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I encode and decode a base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string)

Comment: NO. It didn't work for me. let's say, for example, that I want to write those bytes to a file and get a valid PDF file. what should I do ?

Comment: This will probably answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741612/2809221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the [raw body using `ReadAsStringAsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589539/how-do-i-get-the-raw-request-body-from-the-request-content-object-using-net-4-a), then use [Convert.FromBase64String()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-5.0) to convert it to bytes.

```
string base64 = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("test.pdf", bytes);
```